# I have 2 UIView: 1st is self.view and movieView( maked in XIB ). I can't see video in this UIView, only audio track

Tags: iphone, ios

```
moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = (int)(moviePlayerController.duration / slice ) * source.tag;

[movieView addSubview: moviePlayerController.view];
[[self view] addSubview:movieView];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

With click custom PLAY button my self.view flips to movieView ... i see my made in XIB movieView, w/o video (

Thank you

---

Ok. my bad. my second View has been UIImageView and i did change to UIView..
if i insert

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                       forView:[self view]
                         cache:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
self.view = moviePlayerController.view;
[moviePlayerController stop];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

Then appear movie w/o FlipAnimation - switch beetwen mainView and movieView

if i'm insert [[self view] addSubview:movieView] then i'll look only created in XIB playerView ( linked to movieView ), but no see video, only hear audio. what a problem?

Comment: a very basic question I have to ask: when you say that you're only getting audio, does that mean that the screen is pitch black, or that the screen displays the Q for QuickTime?  (a screenshot would be perfect)

Answer (score 0):

Just need use in init section:

```
[self.view insertSubview:startView atIndex:0];
[self.view insertSubview:videoView atIndex:1];
```

and in change action write this:

```
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
```

and return to startView write again:

```
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:0];
```

like

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```